# is there any difference between a call from contract and web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design, contract-deployment

What is the difference between call made from a contract and web3. I was going through an example and in coments it was mentioned not to make a call from within the contract. Shouldnt calling from a contract and web3 equally expensive?

```
   This method MUST NEVER be called by smart contract code. First, it's 
     fairly
    ///  expensive (it walks the entire Persons array looking for persons 
    belonging to owner),
         ///  but it also returns a dynamic array, which is only supported 
       for web3 calls, and
     ///  not contract-to-contract calls.
  function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) public view returns(uint256[] 
     ownerTokens) {
uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
if (tokenCount == 0) {
    // Return an empty array
  return new uint256[](0);
} else {
  uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
  uint256 totalPersons = totalSupply();
  uint256 resultIndex = 0;

  uint256 personId;
  for (personId = 0; personId <= totalPersons; personId++) {
    if (personIndexToOwner[personId] == _owner) {
      result[resultIndex] = personId;
      resultIndex++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a *read only* function from web3js, that call doesn't consume any gas.

When that same read only function is called by a smart contract method executed by the ethereum vm, it costs gas.